# Can DMS migration use wildcard range for schema?

Tags: amazon-web-services, migration, wildcard, dms

I am using AWS DMS to migrate data from one postgres db to another postgres db and would like to spread the migration into multiple replication tasks. Ideally I would like to do so by splitting the schema range into alphabetical chunks using wildcard ranges. For example I had hoped that a wildcard of "[a-c]%" would migrate all schema starting with a, b or c. According to the following link such wildcards are allowed but in fact they don't work:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Tasks.CustomizingTasks.TableMapping.SelectionTransformation.Wildcards.html

Only limited use of "%" seems successful. Has anyone been able to use more complicated wildcarding for DMS migration schema?

Answer (score 1):

There are a range of wildcards you can use on schemas for DMS

- `%`  Zero or more characters
- `_`  A single character
- `[_]`    A **literal** underscore character
- `[ab]`   A set of characters. For example, `[ab]` matches either 'a' or 'b'.
- `[a-d]`  A range of characters. For example,`[a-d]` matches either 'a', 'b', 'c', or

[Source: Wildcards in table mapping](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Tasks.CustomizingTasks.TableMapping.SelectionTransformation.Wildcards.html)

Comment: Thanks, I saw that page at the time and tried what was recommended but in practice it didn't work

Comment: In my case I was looking to exclude a `_Migrations` table, so all the strings I entered kept being invalid. The final exclusion was very simple, using source table name like `[_]%`, exclude.